# How to manage complex class dependencies in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, object

I'm writing a PHP script that generates SVG plans for all the components that make up a pinball machine, to send to a laser cutter. There are many dozens of components. Each one is defined in a separate class file, something like this:

```
class CabinetFrontComponent extends Component {

    public $width;
    public $height;

    function __construct() 
    {
      /* 
       * Geometry of each component is calculated in its constructor. For 
       * the sake of simplifying this example, I'll just set these two
       * properties to a numeric value.
       */
      $this->width = 150;
      $this->height = 150; 
    }

    function draw()
    {
      // Draws the component and writes an SVG file to disk    
    }

  }
```

The components are all loaded and drawn like this:

```
foreach (glob(__DIR__ . "/components/*.php") as $filename) {
  require_once($filename);
}

foreach( get_declared_classes() as $class ){
  if( is_subclass_of( $class, 'Component' ) ) {
    $obj = new $class;
    $obj->draw();
  }
}
```

The problem is that some components' geometry can't be calculated until another component has first been calculated.  For example, the dimensions of the CabinetSidesComponent can't be calculated until we know the PlayfieldComponent dimensions, and that component can't be calculated until we know the BumperComponent dimensions.

Is there some way I can tell PHP to instantiate these in the right order, so that all the necessary dependencies are met?  I mean, short of manually specifying the order to load them?

Also, once the components have been instantiated, what is the best way to make their properties accessible from other objects?

Comment: looks to like a classic **[php autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)** situation.  Classes will be loaded 'just in time'.

Comment: Sounds like you could use some sort of [IoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control). Have a look at http://php-di.org/

Comment: You could add a static method that returns the list of requirements and then when looping over them, check if the requirements have been loaded already and if not, put it in another array and load after the rest has been loaded. If the requirement tree is just two levels that would be enough.

Comment: Or just add an order to the classes through their names (APartLoadsFirst,  ZCabinetLoadsLast).